Klondike Solitaire as an NP-complete game
I am not a mathematician. I am trying to understand if the paper "The complexity of solitaire" that shows this game is NP-complete also has a implicit assumption that a given hand can only be played once (i.e. is a single-shot rule). In other words a given hand cannot be replayed using information gathered from previous failed attempts to find a solution.
Here is the full information on the paper:
Luc Longpré and Pierre McKenzie, The complexity of solitaire, Theor. Comput. Sci. 410, No. 50, 5252-5260 (2009), MR2573977, Zbl 1194.68123.

I don't know about this specific case, but usually proofs of NP-completeness do not rely on any assumptions about missing information since problems in NP by definition provide all relevant information to the problem-solver. Is there a specific reason that you think this one might?

Yes - I find that using information from previously played hands I can find a solution to more than 60% of hands within 2 or 3 plays. There are some instance that take more plays and other instances that are very difficult are likely NP.
There seems to be an unstated assumption in the original rules from a couple of centuries ago when played with cards that the search for a solution was done in only one try. With the advent of the digital form of the game hands can be replayed using information gleaned from failed hands

NP-completeness just means that some cases of the problem are hard - it's fine if these cases are very rare, so rare that they would never occur in practice with random hands. So this isn't really any evidence on the question.

That is what I was looking for "some cases of the problem are hard" are hard and NP-complete while other are simple and P or intermediate NP cases using information from previous plays of a given hand
Given any hand there are two possible decisions
(1) is there a solution (yes/no)
(2) is the solution optimal i.e. done in the fews number of moves (yes/no)
I can see that #2 is NP but from what you said it seems #2 can range from P to NP
Does this sound correct?

That just isn't how NP is defined. One can't say an individual problem like a hand of solitaire is or isn't NP-complete. Rather NP-completeness is a property of an infinite sequence of problems like all possible hands of solitaire (after generalizing solitaire to larger decks of cards so that there are infinitely many possible hands). If a sequence (called for historical reasons a language) is NP-complete then every member is contained in a NP-complete subsequence and every member is contained in a subsequence in P.

So even though a large percentage of all possible hands can be solved quickly using information from previously played hands and solitaire has been shown to be NP-complete (see link to paper) that solitaire can still be classified as NP-complete
